# mysql query error when an AS is in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This query works fine for me:

```
$query = "
         SELECT 
           p.topnode_id,
           p.param_key,
           p.param_value 
         FROM
           tbl_params p
         INNER JOIN
           tbl_clients c
         ON
           c.client_id = p.client_id
         WHERE
           p.client_id = ?
         ";
```

However, if I put `AS` in the query it throws me an error:

```
$query = "
         SELECT 
           p.topnode_id AS topnode_id,
           p.param_key AS key,
           p.param_value AS value
         FROM
           tbl_params p
         INNER JOIN
           tbl_clients c
         ON
           c.client_id = p.client_id
         WHERE
           p.client_id = ?
         ";
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape `key` with backticks since it is a reserved word in Mysql

```
as `key`
```

Comment: Wow, so quick answer. Never had an idea that 'key' will be a reserved word. Thanks amigo.